# how to create a service to retrieve a shared value

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 13 application and I have a UserRole service that
I have used in many pages.

But I cannot get the value of this object.
I call the services in the main component but when I get the results i have undefined.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserRoleService {

  _userRole!: UserRole;

  get userRole(): UserRole {
    if (!this._userRole) {
      this.getUserRole();
    }
    return this._userRole;
  }

  getUserRole(): any {
    this._httpClient.get<UserRole>(this.requestUrlBase+ "/role", { headers: this.h }).subscribe({
      next: (res: UserRole) => {
        this._userRole = res;
      },
    });
  }
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  providers: [UserRoleService],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
...
  role!: UserRole;


  constructor(userRoleService: UserRoleService, ...,) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userRoleService.getUserRole();

    ...
    this.role = this.userRoleService.userRole;
  }
```

Comment: Your issue is that the http call won’t have resolved by the time you try to assign the value of your user info. Look up the pattern for BehaviorSubject service to get an idea around how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

this function `getUserRole()` is async function - it's sending HTTP request, so ofcourse it will not filled the variable when you return it - `return this._userRole;`

I suggest storing the `Observable` in the service as is:

```
_userRole: Observable<UserRoll> = this._httpClient.get<UserRole>(this.requestUrlBase+ "/role", { headers: this.h })
```

and `subscribe` to the value inside the component

if you want to make only one request to the server you can do it that way:
in the service:

```
getUserRole(): any {
 if (!!this._userRole) {
    return of(this._userRole) 
 }
 return this._httpClient.get<UserRole>(this.requestUrlBase+ "/role", { 
 headers: this.h }).pipe(
   tap(user => this._userRole = user)
 )
```

this way you'll make an HTTP request only if there's no user

Comment: I would like to call services only once

Comment: what do you mean? every place that you need it - you need to inject the service

Comment: I want to call the backend only 1, and not every time I inject the component

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getUserRole` method to return a promise instead something like

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

export class UserRoleService {

  _userRole!: UserRole;
   async getUserRole(): Promise<UserRole> {
    if(!!this._userRole){
      return Promise.resolve(this._userRole);
    }
   let userRole= this._httpClient.get<UserRole>(this.requestUrlBase+ "/role", { headers: this.h });
   this._userRole=await lastValueFrom(userRole);
   return Promise.resolve(this._userRole);
  }
}
```

then and await for the promise to resole in your component

```
this.userRoleService.getUserRole().then((role)=>{
   this.role=role;
})
```

if you are not using the latest version of rxjs and lastValueFrom is not available then use toPromise instead

```
let userRole= this._httpClient.get<UserRole>(this.requestUrlBase+ "/role", { headers: this.h }).toPromise();
   this._userRole=await userRole;
```

Comment: This works fine, but given that Angular uses RxJS and reactive programming it’s easier achieved using observables/behaviorSubjects instead of promises.

Comment: @Levidps 2+2 is 4 , 3+1 is also 4 it depends which way you want to go